# Generate a custom formated string with python

Tags: python, uuid

I have a Javascript code that generates a string (similar to uuid) string

Here it is the js code:

```
var t = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
  , i = (new Date).getTime();
return e = t.replace(/[x]/g, function() {
    var e = (i + 16 * Math.random()) % 16 | 0;
    return i = Math.floor(i / 16),
    e.toString(16)
})
```

How can I generate this string with python?

Comment: `binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(5))`

Comment: People seem to think that you're asking how to generate random UUIDs; you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: @Rawing thx. I think it's fixed now

Comment: reopened because this is a duplicate, but still, the question makes no sense. This is not **UUID** because the *type* field is *wrong*. Also why would you want to generate "Universally" unique identifiers that wouldn't be universally unique (using this code will lead to your UUID not being universally unique). Also this question shouldn't have the Javascript tag, because the question is not about javascript.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thx for ur hint. It's about javascript. The person who is gonna answer it should know about javascript(at least fundamentals)

Comment: It is absolutely not. The knowledge of Javascript doesn't help them formulate the code in Python.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I changed it. I think it makes sense more than before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using regular expression substitution and the new `secrets` module of Python 3.6 - this is not equivalent to the JavaScript code because *this Python code* is cryptographically secure and it generates less collisions / repeatable sequences.

The [`secrets` documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html):

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

```
>>> import re
>>> from secrets import choice
>>> re.sub('x', 
           lambda m: choice('0123456789abdef'), 
           'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx')
'5baf40e2-13ef-4692-8e33-507b-40fb84ff'
```

You'd want this for your IDs to be truly as unique as possible, instead of the [Mersenne Twister MT19937](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) -using `random` which actually is built to specifically yield a *repeatable* sequence of numbers.

For Python <3.6 you can do

```
try:
    from secrets import choice
except ImportError:
    choice = random.SystemRandom().choice
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer :)

Comment: @zaph the quality of `Math.random()` is not guaranteed. Additionally, only 4 bits lowest order bits of the current time is used in the JavaScript code.

Comment: @zaph it is not `choice`, it is `secrets.choice`

Comment: @zaph that's why there is documentation

Comment: Well named functions and variables make for easier to understand and maintain code and, reduce the WTF/minute rate. Really, would it kill the developer to use a descriptive name? Might as well use a random name generator and just read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides [`UUID`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/uuid.html) generation by default:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('bd65600d-8669-4903-8a14-af88203add38')
>>> str(uuid.uuid4())
'f50ec0b7-f960-400d-91f0-c42a6d44e3d0'
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'9fe2c4e93f654fdbb24c02b15259716c'
```

Comment: The OP's code creates a UUID with an algorithm based on the current time. This code doesn't use the same algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want some random hex digits:

```
from random import randint
'-'.join(''.join('{:x}'.format(randint(0, 15)) for _ in range(y)) for y in [10, 4, 4, 4, 10])
```

Where 10, 4, 4, 4, 10 are lengths of each segment in your format string. You may want to add a seed, but basically this does what your JS code does, producing strings like `'f693a7aef0-9528-5f38-7be5-9c1dba44b9'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: bwt, its [8, 4, 4, 4, 8]