# list of random codes like this : (XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX) on python

Tags: python, string, random

hello i want to generate list of random string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits and the code i want to be like this : XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX (15 character with -) and the generator asking of what number of codes you want to generate . thanks you <3

Comment: SO is not a free code writing site.  Post what you have tried, and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at: [Generate a custom formated string with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45670876/2063361)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits

CHAR_SET = ascii_uppercase + digits


def get_integer(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass


def get_random_code(chunks=3, delim='-'):
    def get_random_str(length=5):
        return ''.join(choice(CHAR_SET) for _ in range(length))
    return delim.join(get_random_str() for _ in range(chunks))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_combos = get_integer('Enter # of combos to generate: ')
    for _ in range(total_combos):
        print(get_random_code())
```

Comment: its gives me this error when i try to run it on pycharm   https://imgur.com/paa4ZY5

Comment: Hello thanks for replay i do everything okay i copy and paste than when i try to run he gives me this error message https://imgur.com/a/1RA61Lf

Comment: thanks its works :D i just need little help but can we talk in private ?

Comment: i send u a message check your inbox :)

Comment: hello can you edit the script i want the codes results to be saved as codes.txt ? thank you